# GWT project changes after compile

Tags: gwt

I have big maven GWT project. I have added one column to my grid in one module. When I check it through debug from Development mode everything is OK(the column is full of data). But when I create war file and deploy it on Tomcat7 the column appears but its empty(without any data). After creating war file if I try debug mode I cant see any data too. But if I add any changes to file , save it and run debug again its ok again, full of data.
Why after making war package I cant see any data? What happens after compile?

Comment: Do you `mvn clean` before you `mvn package` for deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many reason for this kind of bug.
1st of all debug mode and real deployment doesn't run the same way. Debug mode is a full java execution associated with a browser plugins which manage the display whereas the war will be deployed as a full html / js client that asynchronously calls your server services, rendering could so be different.

Otherwise it could be a synchronization problem due to difference of execution speed between the 2 modes, your view could be generated before the data are available in a way and after in other one, assuming no refresh mechanism is implemented.

Otherwise it' may be a js compilation problem, check compilation output.

Comment: The data is been taken from my DataBase

Comment: When everything is OK grid column shows current values from DB